# Promise in series duplicate code avoiding

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Using the javascript promise, i have to create a ES6 class that need to do the following function

```
list() {
        if(this.isConnected){
            return ActilityAPI.list().then(result => {
                return result
            });
        }else{
            return this.connect().then(() => {
                return ActilityAPI.list().then(result => {
                    return result
                });
            })
        }
}
```

As you can see, there is a part of the code i need to write several. By sync function, it would be easier, like :

```
list() {
        if(this.isConnected) this.connect()
        return ActilityAPI.list()
}
```

I want to try the same algorithm but with promise. How can i do ?

## EDIT

Thanks to alexmac, i would like to try the ES7 way, so i did the following :

```
list() {
        // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return (async () => {
            if (!this.isConnected) await this.connect();
            return ActilityAPI.list()
        })
}
```

i tried too by adding tje asyncbefore the list() but it won't compile

Comment: Note the `result => { return result }` handler on your promise does literally nothing.

Comment: `list(){ return this.isConnected? ActilityAPI.list(): this.connect().then(() => ActilityAPI.list()) }`

Comment: @Thomas looks like the connection is itself a promise.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, exactly. What's the point?

Comment: @Thomas so why have an extraneous property `isConnected`? Just make `this.isConnected` the promise from the connection function and chain off of it.

Comment: @JaredSmith here is my isConnected property :

get isConnected() {
        if (this._access_token)
            return (Date.now() < this._expiration_date) ? true : false
        else return false;
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use ES6 class and ES7 async/awit the code might look like this:

```
class db {
  async list() {
    if (!this.isConnected) {
      await this.connect();
    }
    return ActilityAPI.list();
 }
```

Comment: If `list()` is a standalone arrow function, how is `this` referring to the parent object? Also, you don't need the `self = this` hack when working with arrow functions because the values of `this` will be preserved inside the arrow function.

Comment: @alexmac i would like to try the es7 way, who look more readable, in a class. Can you please tell me about my edit ?

Comment: @AtesGoral you're right in the absence of the need to save the context when using the arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.connected = someFunctionThatConnects();
  }

  list () {
    return this.connected.then(() => ActilityAPI.list());
  }
}
```

where `someFunctionThatConnects` returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner, thanks to the ternary operator, you could do this:

```
const list = () => 
    (!this.isConnected ? 
        this.connect() : 
        Promise.resolve())
    .then(() => ActilityAPI.list())
```

Where Promise.resolve creates a new Promise and resolves it immediately, calling the then-Handler.

Inside a class, the const is clearly obsolete.

But after reading the other answers, i think the way to go would be to extract the check-and-connect promise to an own function, like that:

```
class {
    connectIfNotConnected = () => 
        !this.isConnected ? 
            this.connect() : 
            Promise.resolve();

    list = () =>
        this.connectIfNotConnected()
        .then(() => ActilityAPI.list())
}
```

Because if there are more operations on the API, you need to check again, on this way you have a function which does exactly that, no matter how.
It just needs to return a Promise when it is ready.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged; would you mind explaining what you're doing so future readers can more easily understand?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a concise way your code can be rewritten:

```
list() {
    const ensureConnected = this.isConnected
        ? Promise.resolve()
        : this.connect();

    return ensureConnected.then(() => ActilityAPI.list());
}
```

Comment: You're losing context in `then(ActilityAPI.list);`, if `this` is used in `list`, the it will be point to another object.